# Average Datatable DateTime rows by TIME only

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda, dataset, average

I have a sproc that returns values for every 15 minutes between 7am and 7pm over the last 5 days. The return resembles this:

```
TheDate                 TheValue
2013-10-06 07:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 07:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 07:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 08:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 08:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 08:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 08:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 09:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 09:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 09:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 09:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 10:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 10:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 10:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 10:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 11:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 11:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 11:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 11:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 12:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 12:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 12:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 12:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 13:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 13:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 13:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 13:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 14:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 14:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 14:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 14:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 15:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 15:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 15:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 15:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 16:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 16:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 16:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 16:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 17:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 17:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 17:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 17:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 18:00:00.000 0
2013-10-06 18:15:00.000 0
2013-10-06 18:30:00.000 0
2013-10-06 18:45:00.000 0
2013-10-06 19:00:00.000 0
2013-10-07 07:15:00.000 0
2013-10-07 07:30:00.000 0
2013-10-07 07:45:00.000 0
2013-10-07 08:00:00.000 0
2013-10-07 08:15:00.000 0
2013-10-07 08:30:00.000 2
2013-10-07 08:45:00.000 11
2013-10-07 09:00:00.000 21
2013-10-07 09:15:00.000 28
2013-10-07 09:30:00.000 15
2013-10-07 09:45:00.000 11
2013-10-07 10:00:00.000 26
2013-10-07 10:15:00.000 1
2013-10-07 10:30:00.000 18
2013-10-07 10:45:00.000 31
2013-10-07 11:00:00.000 28
2013-10-07 11:15:00.000 22
2013-10-07 11:30:00.000 28
2013-10-07 11:45:00.000 32
2013-10-07 12:00:00.000 34
2013-10-07 12:15:00.000 29
2013-10-07 12:30:00.000 23
2013-10-07 12:45:00.000 0
2013-10-07 13:00:00.000 1
2013-10-07 13:15:00.000 20
2013-10-07 13:30:00.000 32
2013-10-07 13:45:00.000 30
2013-10-07 14:00:00.000 32
2013-10-07 14:15:00.000 21
2013-10-07 14:30:00.000 19
2013-10-07 14:45:00.000 23
2013-10-07 15:00:00.000 33
2013-10-07 15:15:00.000 3
2013-10-07 15:30:00.000 22
2013-10-07 15:45:00.000 42
2013-10-07 16:00:00.000 32
2013-10-07 16:15:00.000 34
2013-10-07 16:30:00.000 27
2013-10-07 16:45:00.000 18
2013-10-07 17:00:00.000 5
2013-10-07 17:15:00.000 0
2013-10-07 17:30:00.000 0
2013-10-07 17:45:00.000 1
2013-10-07 18:00:00.000 0
2013-10-07 18:15:00.000 0
2013-10-07 18:30:00.000 0
2013-10-07 18:45:00.000 0
2013-10-07 19:00:00.000 0
```

That's for 2 days, the actual sproc would return 5 days worth but all in that format.

Anyhow, I need to get the average value for each time over all of the days returned. So the average value for 7:15, 7:30, etc.

I have a list of all of the unique times, 7am to 7pm in 15 minute increments, stored in a List of DateTimes

```
List<DateTime> time = new List<DateTime>();

foreach (DateTime a in time)
     Console.WriteLine(a.TimeOfDay);
```

The returned data from the sproc is saved in a DataTable inside of a DataSet. I was hoping to do something similar to this, except I'm missing a key component in there Where clause that I would be very grateful if someone could help with!

```
        List<int> blah = new List<int>();

        foreach (DateTime a in time)
        {
            blah.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                                 .Where(w => /* **NOTE** */)
                                                 .Average(g => Convert.ToInt32(g["TheValue"]))));
        }
```

**NOTE - I need to figure out what to put here to get all the rows where the time is 7:15 or all the rows where the time is 7:30, regardless of date.

So, does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to go about averaging the values for each TIME across all 5 days might be?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to precalculate the list of times by 15 minute increments.  If you just want to average by time of day from all of the data returned by your proc, then you can do it with a LINQ query like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

...

var results = from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    group row by ((DateTime) row["TheDate"]).TimeOfDay
    into g
    select new
            {
                Time = g.Key,
                AvgValue = g.Average(x => (int) x["TheValue"])
            };
```

You can then enumerate through the result and show the time and average value for that time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Works like a charm. Sorry for the late reply on this. :)